# How can I run a file using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, operating-system

Im trying to make this program for my employer that lets a user input what we have in inventory. My plan for this is to have a main .py file that will act as a "Main Menu", GUI sort of thing.  And when the user presses a button, it will open up another .py file that has another GUI in it for what they need.
I don't know the code is to run a file using Python.
At first, I thought I would be able to use:

```
import os
os.system("[command that opens another file]")
```

but I couldn't find that command anywhere without having to edit the computers environment variables first, which is not an option because this program will run on many computers.

***Other info:  Running Windows 10, Using Python 2.7 and Tkinter for the GUI***

Comment: The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module may be helpful.

Comment: Or, since both programs are in Python, you should probably be able to import one into the other.

Comment: What about execfile (builtin)?

Comment: Try just using a command to open the file eg. OS.system('filename'). If Python is installed it should automatically open as in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use the filename as a command and Python is installed then it should open anyway.

```
os.system("myfile.py")
```